# MVC-Sub Menu does not display when using javascript/jquery in my .cshtml file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

when i use the following code in my .cshtml file, sub menus are not displayed:
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

I want to use javascript function in my .cshtml file

Comment: Some sub menus require jQuery UI as well especially those which are animated. Please double check whether you need to include this as well.

Comment: Failing that, you might want to provide more detail and give us some example code